# Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.sensortower.usage:event-emitter-lib:1.0.0

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Gradle build shows error in Android Studio 4.1.1 with above error while trying to build the project that I cloned from github "https://github.com/jarvanh/pulse-sms-android"

Also it shows

> Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project.
> Here **Gradle offline mode** is turning ON and OFF automatically.

*What I tried:*

1. Changing the gradle version
2. Changing the gradle plugin version.

But nothing is working.

[image: This is what happens when we try to build the app]

Any help is appreciated. Heartful thanks in advance.